# How to fix compile errors when including emscripten headers?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, header-files, emscripten

I'm trying to use emscripten [Embind](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/porting/connecting_cpp_and_javascript/embind.html) to bind C++ functions to JavaScript. Unfortunately I already get compile errors when including the specific header file with `#include <emscripten/bind.h>`.

I checked my emscripten environment and set an additonal `Include Directory` in VS2013 to the absolute path of the installation folder (also tried `$(EMSCRIPTEN);` and adapted the inlcude statement).

When compiling my project, I get 20+ compile errors:

```
17>d:\program files\emscripten\emscripten\1.25.0\system\include\emscripten\wire.h(24): error C2144: syntax error : 'bool' should be preceded by ';'
17>d:\program files\emscripten\emscripten\1.25.0\system\include\emscripten\wire.h(24): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
17>d:\program files\emscripten\emscripten\1.25.0\system\include\emscripten\wire.h(39): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'TYPEID'
17>          d:\program files\emscripten\emscripten\1.25.0\system\include\emscripten\wire.h(42) : see reference to class template instantiation 'emscripten::internal::CanonicalizedID<T>' being compiled
17>d:\program files\emscripten\emscripten\1.25.0\system\include\emscripten\wire.h(39): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
17>d:\program files\emscripten\emscripten\1.25.0\system\include\emscripten\wire.h(54): error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'TYPEID'
...
```

I tried emscripten 1.22.0 and 1.25.0 and verified my emscripten environment following [those](http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/building_from_source/verify_emscripten_environment.html) instructions. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, of the MS Visual Studio editions, only VS2010 is supported in Emscripten.

http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/docs/getting_started/getting_started_with_emscripten_and_vs2010.html#getting-started-emscripten-from-visual-studio